# Get error after disabling a module

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade, third-party-module, magento2.4.0

I have upgraded Magento from 2.2.4 to 2.4.0, i have custom modules that are not compatible with the new Magento version.
So i disabled the module but when i run

```
 php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

I got this error

```
In ClassReader.php line 43:
                                                                  
Class Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper does not exist  
                                                                  

In ClassReader.php line 36:
                                                                  
Class Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper does not exist
```

Comment: Are you getting error in any extension ?

Comment: Yes in custom extension shopby from Amasty

Comment: Remove var/cache/* and generated/* before running compile commands

Answer (score 2):

Class **Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper** is not exist in **magento 2.4**, it's exist in **magento2.2.X** and
**magento2.3.X** **version** for error resolution you need to **upgrade your third party extension for magento2.4.x version.**

Comment: I have removed the module folder, but why if i disable it, it gives an error related to the disabled module?

Comment: Please share the error.

Comment: In ClassReader.php line 43:
                                                                  
Class Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper does not exist  
                                                                  

In ClassReader.php line 36:
                                                                  
Class Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper does not exist

Comment: Please find same class  in your another third party modules same class they are used or not. OR disable the third party modules one by one and after check.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried all of this?

```
rm -rf var/*
rm -rf generated/*
rm -rf pub/static/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try to run the command :-**

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: it doesn't work